# I am using turtle and there is a problem: when the name is given,the turtle window closes, does anybody know whats wrong?

Tags: python, python-3.x, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

This happens at line 10. there is no error message.
sorry if you dont understand the notes they are in french but they are basically just describing what the code does. Basically, what i am trying to do is draw a david's star asking the user for some of the parameters. It was working fine before i added screensize, but even after I tried deleting

```
import turtle #importer turtle pour pouvoir l'utiliser
from random import random #importer random pour pouvoir laisser le choix à l'ordinateur. Le choix sera aléatoire.
from turtle import Screen, Turtle  #pour pouvoir utiliser screen turtle, demanderdes questions à l'utilisateur

window = Screen()

colorb = None

while colorb is None:
    colorb = window.textinput("Choose a background color between black, red or yellow", "Color:")
window.bgcolor(colorb)

color= None
while color is None:
    color=window.textinput("quelle couleur voulez vous que les bords soit?","couleur:")
    turtle.pencolor(color)

z=window.textinput("nommez votre fichier(vous ne pouvez qu'utiliser des lettres",'name:')
window.title(z)

turtle.setup(10000,10000)

import turtle
from random import random

x=(window.textinput("choisissez les coordonnées où commencer.","x:"))
y=(window.textinput("choisissez les coordonnées où commencer.","y:"))
s=(window.textinput("choisissez l'épaisseur de l'étoilee","epaisseur"))
nb=int(window.textinput("combien d'étoile","nb"))
p=0

turtle.hideturtle()
turtle.pensize(s)
turtle.pencolor(color)
turtle.up()
turtle.setx(int(x))
turtle.sety(int(y))
turtle.down()
turtle.screensize(10000, 10000)

while p<nb:

        turtle.right(60)
        turtle.forward(50)
        turtle.color(random(), random(), random())
        turtle.pencolor(color)
        turtle.begin_fill() 
        turtle.left(120)
        turtle.forward(50)
        turtle.left(120)
        turtle.forward(50)
        turtle.right(180)
        turtle.end_fill()
        turtle.forward(100)

        turtle.color(random(), random(), random())
        turtle.pencolor(color)
        turtle.begin_fill() 
        turtle.left(120)
        turtle.forward(50)
        turtle.left(120)
        turtle.forward(50)
        turtle.right(180)
        turtle.end_fill()
        turtle.forward(100)

        turtle.color(random(), random(), random())
        turtle.pencolor(color)
        turtle.begin_fill() 
        turtle.left(120)
        turtle.forward(50)
        turtle.left(120)
        turtle.forward(50)
        turtle.right(180)
        turtle.end_fill()
        turtle.forward(100)

        turtle.color(random(), random(), random())
        turtle.pencolor(color)
        turtle.begin_fill() 
        turtle.left(120)
        turtle.forward(50)
        turtle.left(120)
        turtle.forward(50)
        turtle.right(180)
        turtle.end_fill()
        turtle.forward(100)

        turtle.color(random(), random(), random())
        turtle.pencolor(color)
        turtle.begin_fill() 
        turtle.left(120)
        turtle.forward(50)
        turtle.left(120)
        turtle.forward(50)
        turtle.right(180)
        turtle.end_fill()
        turtle.forward(100)

        turtle.color(random(), random(), random())
        turtle.pencolor(color)
        turtle.begin_fill() 
        turtle.left(120)
        turtle.forward(50)
        turtle.left(120)
        turtle.forward(50)
        turtle.right(180)
        turtle.end_fill()

        turtle.pencolor(colorb)
        turtle.up()
        turtle.right(90)
        turtle.forward(1000)
        turtle.down()
        p+=1
```

Comment: *the screentime part but the problem persisted. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Your window size it too big for the screen.

Try

```
turtle.setup(1920, 1080)  # full HD
```

Note that the large screen still accepts input but you can't see the input box.

Comment: it didnt work but it helped me understand i shouldve used width and height. Thank you!